# Mapping between Wikidata and Geonames

Tags: data-request, geospatial, wikidata, data-mapping

Where can I find a mapping between [Wikidata entities](http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3915) and [Geonames entities](http://www.geonames.org/1070940/antananarivo.html)?

*Wikidata:* [image: Worldwide density of geotagged Wikipedia entries] *GeoNames:* [image: Worldwide density of GeoNames entries]

Comment: [`wdt:P1566`](https://wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1566)?

Comment: @StanislavKralin: Wonderful! Could you please make this an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approximately since [October 2014](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Property_proposal/Archive/26#P1566) there exists [GeoNames ID](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1566) external identifier on Wikidata. The current number of entities with this identifier is about 1 500 000.

You could retrive this identifier value for [Antananarivo](http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3915) using the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?geoNamesID WHERE
{
   ?place wdt:P1566 ?geoNamesID 
   VALUES (?place) {(wd:Q3915)}
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FgeoNamesID%20WHERE%0A%7B%0A%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP1566%20%3FgeoNamesID%20%0AVALUES%20%28%3Fplace%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ3915%29%7D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 6):

The [Geonames RDF for Antananarivo](http://sws.geonames.org/1070940/about.rdf) links to Wikipedia:

```
<gn:wikipediaArticle rdf:resource="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antananarivo"/>
```

You should be able to use that to get the corresponding Wikidata entity.